# LaTeX Error: File `shuffle.sty' not found

Tags: packages

I tried to install the shuffle package - https://www.ctan.org/pkg/shuffle

After installation I cannot compile .tex file using the package. This is the error I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `shuffle.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

I have downloaded the package, run `latex shuffle.ins` to obtain `shuffle.sty`, I have copied the `shuffle` directory into `~/texmf` and I have run `texhash ~/texmf`. However, I still get this same error.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you put it in the right place inside `~/texmf`? It needs to be inside `~/texmf/tex/`, probably best `~/texmf/tex/latex/shuffle/`.

Comment: Which tex distribution do you have? Texlive or miktex? One should be able to use the respective package manager to install it in both distributions.

Comment: From a `texlive` distribution on a `Debian-like` package system, it comes from `texlive-science`

Comment: @gigiair - thanks, `texlive-science` did the work.